# Mask property not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The CSS mask is not working in Firefox, but the same CSS is working in Chrome. What do I need to change?

This is what I am currently using:

```css
.web-cam {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 125px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
video {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -125px;
  left: -125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="web-cam">
  <video autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Chrome Browser View

[image: Chrome View]

Firefox Browser View

[image: Firefox View]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image

Comment: You're using a `-webkit-` prefix. This won't work in Firefox _at all_ this should've been apparent from a) the research you should have done and b) the fact Firefox doesn't use Webkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-webkit-mask-image` is the prefixed property of the standard `mask` property [which is **partially** supported by Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks). Browser support is spotty and does not exist in any IE version. Firefox only supports the use of an SVG and not the gradient you are currently using:

> Partial support in WebKit/Blink browsers refers to supporting the mask-image and mask-box-image properties, but lacks support for othe parts of the spec. **Partial support in Firefox refers to only support for inline SVG mask elements i.e. mask: url(#foo)**.

### All is not lost!

The good thing is, there are other options. Here is a basic idea using `overflow: hidden` on the div. The video underneath is "clipped" by the border radius. It will work in any browser that supports the `border-radius` property and HTML5 video. So, just about everywhere.

[image: Works Everywhere]

#### Example

```css
.web-cam {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="web-cam">
  <video autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
</div>
```